Keyboard not responding to input after waking up from sleep
Every time I put my laptop into sleep mode, when it wakes up, the internal keyboard no longer provides input.
I have an external keyboard which will still work perfectly during this event.
Restarting the laptop solves the issue, until it goes to sleep and wakes up.
The weirdest thing though, the keyboard's backlight goes to sleep and turns off after no keys are pressed for a while, it turns back on when I press a key, wth.
I am using a Dell Inspiron with model number P69G, and am running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.

Is this new for you?  I've an XPS laptop that's begun to experience the same behaviour too.  Just looking for a reason.
